# How to get the XML payload property

Tags: wso2, ei

I have a payload as below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <response xmlns="http://edip-api.macausjm-glp.com/apiservice">
                <recipientAddress>zoehuang@asqimacau.com,well168168@gmail.com</recipientAddress>
                <subject>Test email</subject>
                <content>
                    <html>
                        <h1>this is the title</h1>
                        <br />
                        <p>this is the content................</p>
                    </html>
                </content>
            </response>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

I need to get content value like below, how can I get the property?

```
 <html>
     <h1>this is the title</h1>
     <br />
     <p>this is the content................</p>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To store an XML tree in a property use type='OM'

So `<property name="testAmanda" expression="//html" type="OM" />`